flask something wrong with create_app()
Using flask create_app() does not seem to work.
Below is my code
run.py
from gg import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='x.x.x.x', port='XXXX', debug=True)

__init__.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
print("hello1")
def create_app():
   print("hello2")
   return app

on my console I only get 'hello1'
why not create_app working?
And, when I fix init.py as
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
print("hello2")

It gives error of cannot import app from gg
Any help of activation create_app()?

file path : run.py is inside flask_project, and init.py is inside flask_project-gg

sorry.. I gave wrong information with fixed init.py, fixed init.py is like i put `app=Flask(name) inside create_app(), and it gives error cannot import app from gg

from gg import app In this statement, what is gg?  Is that a module you wrote yourself?

First check if your directory is set up like this:
Main_folder/
│
├── gg/
│   └── __init__.py
└── run.py

This way your run.py can find the gg package and run it.
Now the simple mistake in your code is: You never imported or ran create_app() function anywhere
So change the code in run.py to:
from gg import create_app
if __name__ == '__main__':
   gg_app = create_app()
   gg_app.run(host='x.x.x.x', port='XXXX', debug=True)


fixed init.py is like i put `app=Flask(name) inside create_app(), and it gives error cannot import app from gg

Again if you do that app becomes a local variable of that create_app function instead and hence cannot be found to import.
